# How to display 2 ListViews in Flutter with widgets in between

Tags: flutter, dart

I currently have a ListView that displays cards that have several properties and it's being displayed properly within an expanded widget:

```
    return Expanded(
       child: renderCardsList(docs, homeState),
     );
```

Each of these cards have dates and I want to split the list by the current date (to have something like past/upcoming), but I'm having issues displaying 2 ListViews with text in between.

For example, ideally I'd like something like this:

```
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text('Upcoming'),
              renderCardsList(docs1, homeState),
              Text('Past'),
              renderCardsList(docs2, homeState),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

With the entire list being scrollable. I've tried several combinations of adding Expanded widgets, switching columns up, etc with no luck.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Code for renderCardsList

```
  ListView renderCardsList(dynamic list, dynamic state) {
ListView result = ListView.builder(
  itemCount: list.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    
    DocumentSnapshot? snapshot = list[index];

    if (snapshot != null) {
      var snapshotData = snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>

      Object obj = Object(
        id: key,
        name: snapshotData['name'],
        date: snapshotData[‘date’],
      );

        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 5),
          child: Card(
              data: obj,
        );
      }
    }

    return const SizedBox.shrink();
  },
);

return result;
```

}

Comment: Please show the code for `renderCardsList`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51910725/flutter-displaying-two-listviews-on-one-screen does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Update: I didn't figure this out for a ListView but I was able to rewrite my renderCardsList function to return List instead and return those cards through that.

Then you can use them just like this.

```
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text('Upcoming'),
          ...renderCardsList(docs1, homeState),
          Text('Past'),
          ...renderCardsList(docs2, homeState),
        ],
      ),
```

This works for me for now as it's not a large list but would be curious if anyone has a way to use the ListView as I believe it's much more performant for long lists.

Answer (score 0):

You are encountering an issue with the `SingleChildScrollView` that contains `ListView`s.

A `ListView` will attempt to take as much space as possible for its axis. In your case, the vertical axis. However, the vertical axis is unbounded, because a `SingleChildScrollView` has an infinite height.

The solution is simply to tell your `ListView`s to only take up as much space as possible:

```
ListView renderCardsList(List<MyObject> list) {
  return ListView.builder(
    /// When 'shrinkWrap' is set to true, the list will only be as big as its
    /// children, instead of attempting to fill the available space.
    shrinkWrap: true, // <=== RIGHT HERE!
    itemCount: list.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 5.0),
      child: MyCard(object: list[index]),
    ),
  );
}
```

Without `shrinkWrap` being set to `true`, the framework will not be able to lay out your list views in an unbounded vertical axis.

I created mock data and put multiple `ListView`s inside a `Column`, inside a `SingleChildScrollView`:

```
return SingleChildScrollView(
  primary: false,
  child: Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: [
      if (elementsFromThePast.isNotEmpty) ...[
        const Text("Past"),
        renderCardsList(elementsFromThePast),
      ],
      if (elementsForToday.isNotEmpty) ...[
        const Text("Today"),
        renderCardsList(elementsForToday),
      ],
      if (elementsFromTheFuture.isNotEmpty) ...[
        const Text("Future"),
        renderCardsList(elementsFromTheFuture),
      ],
    ],
  ),
);
```

Output using `shrinkWrap`:

[image: layout output]

Here is the full example code:

```
extension DateTimeExtension on DateTime {
  DateTime removeTimeComponents() {
    return DateTime(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0);
  }
}

class MyGroupedListViews extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyGroupedListViews({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final list = getMockList();
    final today = DateTime.now().removeTimeComponents();

    final elementsFromThePast = list
        .where((element) => element.date.isBefore(today))
        .toList(growable: false);

    final elementsForToday =
        list.where((element) => element.date == today).toList(growable: false);

    final elementsFromTheFuture = list
        .where((element) => element.date.isAfter(today))
        .toList(growable: false);

    return SingleChildScrollView(
      primary: false,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          if (elementsFromThePast.isNotEmpty) ...[
            const Text("Past"),
            renderCardsList(elementsFromThePast),
          ],
          if (elementsForToday.isNotEmpty) ...[
            const Text("Today"),
            renderCardsList(elementsForToday),
          ],
          if (elementsFromTheFuture.isNotEmpty) ...[
            const Text("Future"),
            renderCardsList(elementsFromTheFuture),
          ],
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// Mock model.
class MyObject {
  const MyObject({required this.id, required this.name, required this.date});

  final int id;
  final String name;
  final DateTime date;
}

List<MyObject> getMockList() {
  final today = DateTime.now().removeTimeComponents();
  final yesterday = today.subtract(const Duration(days: 1));
  final tomorrow = today.add(const Duration(days: 1));

  return [
    MyObject(id: 0, name: "1", date: yesterday),
    MyObject(id: 1, name: "2", date: today),
    MyObject(id: 2, name: "3", date: yesterday),
    MyObject(id: 3, name: "4", date: tomorrow),
    MyObject(id: 4, name: "5", date: today),
    MyObject(id: 5, name: "6", date: tomorrow),
    MyObject(id: 6, name: "7", date: tomorrow),
  ];
}

/// Mock card to display [MyObject].
class MyCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyCard({super.key, required this.object});

  final MyObject object;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(flex: 1, child: Text(object.name)),
        Expanded(flex: 3, child: Text(object.date.toString())),
      ],
    );
  }
}

/// Mock list view to display [MyCard]s.
///
/// Mock data will be used to populate the list, you can replace it with your
/// own.
ListView renderCardsList(List<MyObject> list) {
  return ListView.builder(
    /// When 'shrinkWrap' is set to true, the list will only be as big as its
    /// children, instead of attempting to fill the available space.
    shrinkWrap: true,
    itemCount: list.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 5.0),
      child: MyCard(object: list[index]),
    ),
  );
}
```